# Thesis Chapter Formatting

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, thesis

I have started trying to customise my thesis formatting. I am using the book document class.

I've been able to follow some tips on here to get e.g. underlined chapter headings etc but I saw a really nice style on this page:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dissertate.io/generic.pdf

Does anyone know an easy way to replicate this? Or at least to have a number with text underneath and flushed to the right?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You can do that with the `titlesec` package. The main font is `ebgaramond`, which is available on CTAN. Note it has (purposely) no bold version.

Comment: see https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv#.Ven1CNJ_Okp

Comment: @touhami I do not think anyone could be more precise, but only an external link is not a fiable answer at long term. Please convert your comment in answer adding a brief information about Dissertate (so it could be still useful in case of broken links).

Comment: @Bernard What makes you say that `ebgaramond` purposely has no bold version? The font designer has, as stated on the font website, every intention of creating it, and I happened to talk with him just a few days ago, and he told me he plans to start working on just that very soon.

Comment: I remembered having read something like that, but you're right. I mixed up the fact that it's based on historical specimens that didn't exist in boldface (as far as I know, these didn't exist in the 16th century), and also I read once in a paper it was better not to use boldface if one wanted to be close to historical printing – actually boldface was considered distasteful.

Comment: @Bernard (Don't forget to @ me when you answer me): There are definitely purists who think that you shouldn't use boldface with font families that existed before boldface came into use (@egreg, e.g., will tell you not to use boldface with Garamond). I don't agree with that view (and the creator of EB Garamond doesn't seem to either), but I'm not going to open up a debate about that here.

Comment: @Sverre: Sorry I forgot  addressing to you. I must say I usually prefer to use `semibold` when it exists, especially amidst ordinary text.

Comment: @Bernard I agree. Bold weights are often too heavy. But I never use bold or semibold with regular text anyway, and I would advise against it (italics is the way to go, and sometimes small caps). Boldface is for headings and captions only, if you ask me. But there are no "right" answers here, only an interplay of tradition and personal taste. But we're getting off topic here, so let's stop this discussion now :)

Comment: @Bernard FWIW I've seen boldface type in books from the 16th and 17th centuries.

Comment: These must have been gothic letters I suppose? They are the ancestors of bold types.

Answer (score 2):

This is from package `quotchap` https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/quotchap

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[palatino]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882}
\begin{document}
\begin{savequote}[8cm]
  ``All changes, even the most longed for, have their melancholy;
  for what we leave behind us is a part of ourselves; we must
  die to one life before we can enter another.''
  \qauthor{Anatole France}
  `The moment a man starts to behave ridiculous to a woman
  you know he is serious at it.'
  \qauthor{Colette}
\end{savequote}
\makeatletter
\chapter{Quote to be quoted}
This is an example of a normal chapter page.

\chapter{Enjoy the whitespace}
This is an example of a chapter without quotes.

\chapter*{More space for tocs and bibs}
This is an example of a non-numbered page.

\begin{savequote}[5cm]
  Who's gonna {\upshape\ttfamily U:\textasciitilde} tonight?
  \qauthor{The Cars}
\end{savequote}
\chapter*{Do not trust everyone}
This is to show there is not much space in the star version chapters.

\end{document}
```